# Herding cats in Italian

Tags: proverbs

How would you say "herding cats" in Italian? I would like to know if there exist an equivalent proverb in Italian.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd use it in that sense, @Gae.S. I'd use “armata Brancaleone” for a heterogenous, haphazard, somewhat laughable set of persons, but not an unmanageable one, as the English idiom seems to mean.

Answer (score 1):

I’m afraid there isn’t a similar idiomatic expression in standard Italian.

I would use

> È un’impresa disperata.

Which indicates that a task is strenuous yet pointless – it’s set for failure.

(However this is a more generic expression, so it wouldn’t be good if you’re specifically referring to trying to manage an uncooperative group).

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Andrea is correct; I add that, less formally, the often used word is "casino" to define a situation difficult to sort out, like: "Capire mio fratello è un casino" ("trying to understand my brother is like herding cats").

This word "casino" ([see Treccani vocabulary](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/casino)) can be used to indicate something disordered and uncontrollable, i.e. caos, like in "il traffico di Milano è un casino" or something difficult to do (because it is uncontrollable).